# How to create a self monitoring threading pattern in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, windows-services

I have a table in a Database of a list of items that need to be checked (imap mailboxes) . The list is dynamic and can change at any time with users been added or deleted. I have created a windows service (in .Net) that reads the table to get all the mailboxes to be checked and processes any new mail that is found.

My first attempt was to populate a queue with the items to process and then recheck the table every few minutes for changes clearing the queue and re-adding items back to it. I used a finite number of threads which dequeue and then enqueue items from the list once processing is complete.

Issues I found was a slow memory leak which I was only able to resolve by poulating the queue once (on startup of the service) and therefore having to restart the service if and changes to my database table happened. second issue is being unable to figure out how to monitor if my finite list of threads were still running.

Any thoughts?

Comment: i know it completely sidesteps your question, but i would do this as a scheduled task. Running your job as a periodic scheduled task has benefits 1.if there is a crash it will automatically restart next scheduled time 2.if there is a memory leak it will get cleaned up momentarily 3.fewer processes running on a server 4. You don't keep a persistent connection to a database.  You're going to be polling anyway, this way the polling happens when the process launches. The disadvantages: the quickest tasks can be run is every 1 minute; so a user might have to wait 60 seconds for her email

Comment: It was a consideration to use scheduled tasks but the delay is the issue. Thanks anyway :)